# Div positioning problems in IE

Tags: html, css

The HTML:

```
<div id="broadcast">
    <div id="broadcast_header">
        Neighbourhood Broadcast
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#broadcast_header
{
 background-color: #A0522D;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Firefox: All fine, header appears 20px above the div, its cool.
IE: Refuses to show div(broadcast_header)!

Overflow: visible
doctype definition: Given

My input: Suppose change top to - top: -5px; It shows the div(header) partially. Thank you :].

Comment: Use the code tags to display code!

Comment: Sounds like it is hidden under the other div. try making it position absolute, and make its parent div position relative.

Comment: I want the parent element to be fixed actually. And making it absolute's not helping, it is getting hid

Answer (score 0):

try top:-10px,it will show in IE and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `height` and `width` css for **#broadcast**

```
#broadcast
{ 
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative
}

#broadcast_header
{
   background-color: #A0522D;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```